# appengine, iphone and gzip

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine, gzip

I have some google appengine java servlet that I access from some iphone 4 app.

The servlet writes the response as XML. I have set the content type of the servlet response to "text/plain". If I fetch the servlet page using Chrome, the response is gzipped (1 Kb). But, if I fetch the servlet using my iphone app, the response is 19 Kb sized...

Either the iphone app fetches data with [`NSData dataWithContentOfURL:url]` or with some NSMutableURLRequest with HTTP header field "Accept-Encoding" set to "gzip", the response is still not gzipped.

Moreover, I can see in Google AppEngine logs that my iphone app accepts gzip : `CFNetwork/485.10.2 Darwin/10.4.0,gzip(gfe)`

What can I do?

Thanks.
François

Comment: How have you confirmed that passing Accept-Encoding: gzip via an NSMutableURLRequest results in an uncompressed response? It gives me a compressed response when I tried - see http://github.com/jabley/iphone-http/blob/master/Classes/NSURLConnectionFetchTask.m

Comment: 'gzip(gfe)' doesn't actually mean that it recognizes your client supports gzip - 'GFE' stands for Google Front End.

Comment: Below are the GAE logs that make me saying that my iphone app doesn't handle gzip requests :
*** iPhone : *** /initialisation 200 48ms 38cpu_ms 19kb myAppName/3.0 CFNetwork/485.10.2 Darwin/10.4.0,gzip(gfe)
*** Chrome : *** /initialisation 200 52ms 39cpu_ms 1kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.63 Safari/534.3,gzip(gfe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way: you have to add "gzip" to the User-Agent.

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL]];
[request addValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

If you do it this way, you will lost default values set by the framework (appName/Version CFNetwork/blah blah blah), but GAE returns a gzipped response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should set `User-Agent`